# Square roots and unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Why is it that for any non-negative matrix $M$ and unitary matrix $U$, we have

$$\sqrt{UMU^\dagger}=U\sqrt{M}U^\dagger$$?

This question has to do with Problem 2c from [this sheet](http://www.physik.rwth-aachen.de/fileadmin/user_upload/www_physik/Institute/Inst_QI/quantum_information_SS2012/set07_01.pdf). I think I am allowed to assume the "fact" but I'd like to know why.

Comment: @GitGud : Perhaps [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Square_roots_of_matrices_and_operators)? Also, I've added the source of the question above, in case it is of any use. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality holds because:

1. Every positive semidefinite matrix $A$ has a unique positive semidefinite square root.
2. Both sides of the given equality are positive semidefinite square roots of $A=UMU^\dagger$ (just square both sides and you will see).